# Is there sampling in the 'scheduled email' reports for Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I've tried searching docs and I can't find anything.

When I attempt to do a test myself the numbers are slightly off when compared to the identical report and date range but set to `High Precision`.

I want to make sure that all reports I get emailed are at the highest precision, but there's no option and I'm not sure what precision the emailed reports are.

[image]

Comment: There is no way to 100% prevent sampling you will need to request smaller amounts of data I suggest limiting the date range until you find the length of time that does not sample.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google analytics reporting within the website and is not programming related.

Comment: There is no way to do this, if you have Google Analytics premium, you can create an unsampled report

Comment: I don't need unsampled (we have billions of pageviews, and even 1-day is sampled at 45% at best). All I want is to make sure the emailed report is the same as the 'most precision' setting (rather than the default, which seems to be right in the middle)

Comment: @Tallboy i know, but it's not configurable, the closest way is to do it with the unsampled, has the same behaviour but take a couple of minutes or hours to generate it, but i dont see any other option related on this. A hard way is create an cronjob, do it via API and send you the email with this information. On the api you can "force" the  unsampling, but the tool can skip this option.